# nGinx, multiple locations serving different SPAs

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I have a very simple config that I want to use to serve multiple single page apps

```
server {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html;

    location ~ ^/spa1/(.*?)$ {
        root /var/www/spa1/;
    }

    location ~ ^/spa2/(.*?)$ {
        root /var/www/spa2/;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

The directory structure of `/var/www/` is as below:

```
www/
|- 404.html        (Generic 404)
|- index.html      (A plain html page with links to the apps)
|- spa1/   
   |- index.html   (the index page for single page app 1)
   |- spa1.js
   |- spa1.css
   |- static/      (folder containing spa1 static files)
|- spa2/
   |- index.html   (the index page for single page app 2)
   |- spa2.js
   |- spa2.css
   |- static/      (folder containing spa1 static files)
```

My understanding was that vising `myserver.com/` would return the `index.html` page in `/var/www`, whereas visiting `myserver.com/spa1/` or `myserver.com/spa2/` would return the respective `index.html` pages for each single page app. However this doesn't seem to be the case- instead if I visit `/spa1` or `/spa2` I get served the root `index.html` page only, as if it's ignoring the `root` directive for each app

As an addendum, is there a more correct way to serve multiple single page apps than the way I'm attempting to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why the URI `/spa1/` would return the file `/var/www/index.html`, with your current configuration. However...

The value of the `root` statement should be `/var/www` for all three cases. The path to the file is calculated by concatenating the value of the `root` statement with the URI.

So your directory structure and URI plan should work with the even simpler configuration of:

```
server {
    root /var/www;
    index index.html;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this won't work as my apps have `static` folders containing images that are referenced in the `index.html` and js/css files- because they will search relative to the root so `/var/www/spa1.css` instead of `/var/www/spa1/spa1.css`. Also, what if the `spa1` and `spa2` folders were named differently to their location uri?

Comment: What is the URI of these static files? You can find it in the `nginx` access log. If the folder names are not consistent with the URI, you will need to use the `alias` directive instead.

Comment: the uri's are all relative, so for example `<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.js>`

Comment: The URI `/static/js/app.js` still contains an absolute path, which means that resources from spa1 and spa2 are pointing to the same place. You may get success by specifying a path relative URI, e.g. `src=static/js/app.js` which is relative to the last `/` in the current URI.

Comment: ah ok, so I think my question is therefore: How do I serve the static files so that "/static/js/app.js" in the index.js looks under the (e.g.) `/spa1/` location?

Comment: So you have URIs `/static/js/app1.js` and `/static/js/app2.js` pointing to files in two different directories. It is not an efficient or scalable model, but you can use `try_files $uri /spa1$uri /spa2$uri =404;` or something similar, to try each directory in turn until a match is found. Please don't use the same name for files in different directories.

Comment: At this point what I'm asking is another question in itself so I'll mark this as answered and do another question